# How to check the list contain the particular string or not in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list like this

```
List<SegmentList> li = new List<SegmentList>();
li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Select", SegId = 0 });
li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Allergy", SegId = 1 });
li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Skin", SegId =2 });
li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Hair", SegId =3 });
li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Fever", SegId = 4 });
li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "All", SegId = 5});
```

And i have a string like this "Allergy,Skin,Cured,Better"
In that list the words "Allergy" and  "Skin" are already there.
I want to add the "Cured" and "better" in that list

I have tried this

```
public ActionResult Index(){

            List<SegmentList> li = new List<SegmentList>();
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Select", SegId = 0 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Allergy", SegId = 1 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Skin", SegId =2 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Hair", SegId =3 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Fever", SegId = 4 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "USA", SegId = 5 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "All", SegId = 6 });
            SegmentList obj = new SegmentList();
            String data = db.Segments.Where(x=>x.Id== userid).Select(x => x.Segname).SingleOrDefault();
            List<string> segmentdata = new List<String>(data.Split(','));
            obj.List = segmentdata;
            string newdata = string.Empty;
            int count=6;
            foreach(string s in segmentdata)
            {
                newdata += s+",";
                count = count + 1;
                li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = newdata.TrimEnd(','), SegId = count });
            }

            obj.seglist = li;
            ViewBag.List = li;
            return View(obj);
        }
```

Comment: Ok, so you have 2 lists, list 1 and list 2, list2 is just and string, and list 1 is a List of segments, Do you want to create new segments for each element that's found in list 2 but not in list 1?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ZoiloReyes Yes...you got Exactly what i want

Comment: Is seg id and the List index the same?

Comment: @ZoiloReyes yes its same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
List<SegmentList> li = new List<SegmentList>();
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Select", SegId = 0 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Allergy", SegId = 1 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Skin", SegId = 2 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Hair", SegId = 3 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "Fever", SegId = 4 });
            li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = "All", SegId = 5 });

            List<string> stringList = new List<string>("Allergy,Skin,Cured,Better".Split(',')) ;

            foreach(var stirng in stringList)
            {
                if(li.Any(x => x.Segname.Equals(stirng)))
                {
                    li.Add(new SegmentList { Segname = stirng, SegId = li.Count });
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the linq any operator?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to separate your string in one array, you can use the method Substring. 
That array will constain 4 elements Allergy,Skin,Cured and Better.
For Each element you verify if your main list contains the element, else you need to get max value from your ID and then  with these values you can insert in your main list.